# Match within certain range but maximum to a specific keyword

Tags: python, regex

The following regular expression will match everything that is between the expression *Peter* and *Parker* as long as *Parker* is found within 0-20 characters after *Peter*: `'Peter[\s\S]{{0,20}}Parker'`

Now I want to match everything as long as Parker is within 0-20 characters except when there is a keyword that appears within this range. When the keyword appears, this should act as the upper range, so that instead of `{0,20}` we will have something like `{0,keyword}` for the range in which Parker should appear.

**Example:**

Let the keyword be "Hulk".

`test1 = "My name is Peter, I like spiders very much Parker"` -> Should not match as Parker is more than 20 characters away from Peter

`test2 = "My name is Peter, Jason Hulk Parker"` -> Should not match. Even though Parker is within the original 0-20 range, the keyword "Hulk" appears in this range and acts as the upper range of the regex.

`test3 = "My name is Peter Jason Parker and I don't like the Hulk"` -> Should match. Parker is within the 0-20 range and Hulk appears out of this range.

Comment: Use `\bPeter(?:(?!Hulk)[\s\S]){0,20}Parker\b`. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/W4P6pd/1

Comment: That is `Peter(?:(?!Peter|Hulk)[\s\S]){0,20}?Parker`, use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900794/3832970).